# Lighthouse error: "Buttons do not have an accessible name"

Tags: html, accessibility

How do I fix this Lighthouse error:

> Buttons do not have an accessible name

```html
<button class="search-button" type="submit" value="Search"></button>
```

Comment: No problem, thanks.... https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.1/button-name?application=lighthouse

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I would recommend this link for reference.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/button-name

It suggests that the button should have inner text content or an aria-label or aria-labelledBy.

```
<button class="search-button" type="submit">Search</button>

<button class="search-button" type="submit" aria-label="search"></button>
```

I have shown a button with inner text and also a button with an aria-label.

Comment: Yes I know that. But I don't know codification :)

Comment: Sure, would you make another question and link it here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56083674/form-elements-do-not-have-associated-labels

Comment: "It suggests that the button should have inner text content, and an aria-label or aria-labelledBy." It only needs inner text or an aria-label not both.

Comment: aria-label attribute should work

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you should add text:

```
<button type="submit">Save...</button>
```

or add aria-label

```
<my-icon type="button" aria-label="save button"></my-icon>
```

Fail:

```
<button id="find"><img src="find.jpg></button>
```

Pass:

```
<button id="find"><img src="find.jpg>Find</button>
```

Source [here](https://accessibilityinsights.io/info-examples/web/button-name/)!