# Lighthouse error: "Form elements do not have associated labels"

Tags: html, label, forms

How do I fix this Lighthouse error:

> Form elements do not have associated labels

```html
<input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="Arama..." onfocus="if (this.value == 'Arama...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Arama...';}">

<select id="main-menu-mob">

<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" maxlength="65525" required="required"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For each of these you can add a label that references the element, or use the `aria-labelledBy` attribute. I think labels are easiest but I will show you one of each.

```
<label for="s">Arama...</label>
<input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="Arama..." onfocus="if (this.value == 'Arama...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Arama...';}">

<label id="lbl-main-menu-mob">Select Item</label>
<select id="main-menu-mob" aria-labelledby="lbl-main-menu-mob">

<label for="comment">Enter Comment</label>
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" maxlength="65525" required="required"></textarea>
```

Comment: great... help loves. Thank you so much.

Comment: creates a problem in mobile vision. Is there an alternative?

Comment: What problem does it create? There are lots of ways to skin this cat, all depends on the use case.

Comment: Greyhound? I don’t understand, what slips into the search box?

Comment: Sorry, My English is not very good. The search box is changing. In mobile view. search text disappears

Comment: If you’re able to share the markup of the label and search input I’ll take a look. Even better would be a codePen or JSfiddle. If not, that’s ok share the code for the search and label in the question above.

Comment: Can I send you in private?

Comment: Sure @Mehmetk send it my way.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `aria-label="lorem ipsum"` to the element

Answer (score 0):

Given this is the top result let me simply say:

In the label element, add a for attribute that matches an id attribute of the input element. So in the example below, for="question" and id="question" have to match exactly, including the case.

```
<label for="question">Question:</label><input type="text" id="question">
```

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/accessibility/test-issues-tool)

Answer (score -3):

You can also try to add `placeholder='lorem ipsum'` to input element.

Comment: [The  placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)