# reactjs - Find Navlink using getByRole in unit test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

In my React Testing Library unit test, I am unable to get the Navlink by role.

```
getByRole('link', { name: 'help' }) - This fails
```

The Navlink does not have text, rather it has a help icon which seems to be the problem.

The error I recieve is:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "link" and name "help"

Here are the accessible roles:

link:

Name "Home":
<a
class="active"
href="home"
name="home"
/>

Name "About":
<a
class="inactive"
href="/about"
name="about"
/>

Name "":          <--- No name for link with icon
<a
class="inactive"
href="/help"
name="help"
/>
```

My NavBar:

```
const NavBar = () => {

  return (
    <>
        <div className="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to="home" className={({isActive}) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}>Home</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to="about" className={({isActive}) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}>About</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <NavLink to="help" name="help" className={({isActive}) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}><FaQuestionCircle size='1.5rem' className="helpicon"/></NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

The failing unit test:

```
describe(Navbar, () => {

    const mockedNavigation = jest.fn();
    
    it('should navigate to help page', () => {
        
        const { getByRole } = render(<Navbar />, { wrapper: Router });
        fireEvent.click(getByRole('link', { name: 'help' }));

        expect(mockedNavigation).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            "help", 
            {
                preventScrollReset: undefined,
                relative: undefined,
                replace: false,
                state: undefined,
                unstable_viewTransition: undefined
            });
    });
});
```

How do I select a Navlink that does not have text, but uses an icon instead?

Maybe I can use classNames? Add an additional class as well as the active/inactive?
Another method would be easier though and more readable.

Comment: It has no [accessible name](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/names-and-descriptions/), which means it's _not accessible_. Your question shouldn't be how else to select it, rather how to make it accessible - https://stackoverflow.com/q/56082381/3001761, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<NavLink/>` component can't accept the `name` property. If you use TypeScript, you will get a TS-type error:

```
Type '{ children: Element; to: string; name: string; className: ({ isActive }: NavLinkRenderProps) => "active" | "inactive"; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & NavLinkProps & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>'.
  Property 'name' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & NavLinkProps & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>'.ts(2322)
```

Instead, you can pass a `title` prop to the icon component as the accessible name of the `<NavLink/>`. E.g.

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faQuestionCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/home" className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}>
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/about" className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}>
              About
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/help" className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faQuestionCircle} className="helpicon" title="help" />
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

`NavBar.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

describe('Navbar', () => {
  it('should navigate to help page', () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/help']}>
        <NavBar />
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );
    const navLink = screen.getByRole('link', { name: 'help' });
    console.log(' ~ it ~ navLink:', navLink);
    fireEvent.click(navLink);
    expect(navLink).toHaveClass('active');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/77897051/NavBar.test.tsx
  Navbar
    √ should navigate to help page (109 ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.627 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

package version:

```json
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.21.1",

"jest": "^29.7.0",
"jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
```

Answer (score 2):

The link role *should technically* work if the link is accessible, e.g. using an ARIA label on the rendered icon

```
<NavLink
  to="help"
  className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}
>
  <FaQuestionCircle size='1.5rem' className="helpicon" aria-label="help" />
</NavLink>
```

but if you have trouble targeting a component you have a few other options available to you:

- Add a `data-testid` attribute to the element and use the `*byTestId` query.

  https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid

  ```
  const NavBar = () => {
    return (
      <div className="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <NavLink
              data-testid="link-home"
              to="home"
              className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}
            >
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink
              data-testid="link-about"
              to="about"
              className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}
            >
              About
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink
              data-testid="link-help"
              to="help"
              className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}
            >
              <FaQuestionCircle size='1.5rem' className="helpicon" />
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul> 
      </div>
    );
  };
  ```

  ```
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Navbar />, { wrapper: Router });
  fireEvent.click(getByTestId('link-help'));
  ```
- You can also always use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) on the rendered `container`.

  https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#manual-queries

  ```
  const NavBar = () => {
    return (
      <div className="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <NavLink
              to="home"
              className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}
            >
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink
              to="about"
              className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}
            >
              About
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink
              to="help"
              className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}
            >
              <FaQuestionCircle size='1.5rem' className="helpicon" />
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul> 
      </div>
    );
  };
  ```

  A Query similar to `"a[href='/help']"` or `"a[href='/help'].inactive"`:

  ```
  const { container } = render(<Navbar />, { wrapper: Router });
  fireEvent.click(container.querySelector("a[href='/help'].inactive"));
  ```

Take a look through the [About Queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about) documentation, there may be other options available to you as well depending on implementation or information that you may've omitted in your post that we're unaware of.

Comment: Thanks Drew, I'd rather not add testid. The query selector is a good idea. Adding title="help" to the icon itself I think is better.